# "multiply defined symbols found" how is my destructor being defined twice?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, pimpl-idiom

Question: What am I doing to cause a multiple definition symbol linker error?

OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx

```
module;

#include <memory>

export module OSFrameworkWindows10Module;

export class OSFramework {
private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> _impl;
public:
    OSFramework();
    ~OSFramework();
};

typedef struct OSFramework::impl {
    impl();
    ~impl();
} impl;

impl::impl()
{}

impl::~impl() = default;

OSFramework::OSFramework() : _impl{ std::make_unique<impl>() } {}
OSFramework::~OSFramework() = default;
```

winmain.cpp

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

import OSFrameworkWindows10Module;

int WINAPI wWinMain (
    _In_ HINSTANCE hinst,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE,
    _In_ PWSTR,
    _In_ int
)
{
    auto os_framework = std::make_unique<OSFramework>();
    return S_OK;
};
```

compiler output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Vegas22Metroidvania1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx
1>Compiling...
1>OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx
1>winmain.cpp
1>OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl OSFramework::~OSFramework(void)" (??1OSFramework@@QEAA@XZ::<!OSFrameworkWindows10Module>) already defined in winmain.obj
1>D:\projects\Vegas22Metroidvania1\x64\Debug\Vegas22Metroidvania1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "Vegas22Metroidvania1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Pretty lost here as to why OSFramework::~OSframework() is being counted as defined more than once.  I'm somehow instantiating it in my winmain.cpp file even though I'm just setting up a smart pointer for the class instance.

Maybe relevant info: I'm using Visual Studio 17.4.3

Comment: Starting a question with a wall of text is a turn-off. [ask] recommends introducing your question before posting *any* code.

Comment: `typedef struct`: You're writing a C++20 module; you're *really far* from a place where `typedef struct` is a useful construct.

Comment: *"I don't know if it's due to [...] or if it has something to do with templates since I'm using `auto...` to pass the parameter pack through to the implementation constructor."* -- this is testable. Remove `auto...` and the parameter pack -- does the error disappear?

Comment: Do you need to mark the out of line definitions as `inline` like you would in a header? (Just a guess, I've not played with modules yet)

Comment: That's a good point about removing the `auto...`, I didn't think of that.  I'm updating the above question to take that out.

Comment: @NicolBolas You say that but clearly I have no idea what you mean because I'm using this idiom still.  I'd appreciate it if you pointed out where I can read up on why you think this is no longer a useful construct.

Comment: @Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeej: "*I'd appreciate it if you pointed out where I can read up on why you think this is no longer a useful construct.*" It's just a C-ism. C++ doesn't have a separate namespace for "struct"s the way C does. It serves no real purpose, and the few times it is theoretically useful can be served by just making a separate `using alias = type_name;` declaration.

Comment: I recall the reason I started doing this in my own code was to save myself from having to type "ClassName::impl" in a lot more places in the source file.  If this is just a comment about style then /shrug.

Comment: @AlanBirtles This suggestion fixed my issue.  I'd appreciate if you put an answer down so I could mark it as the solution.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: If that helps (as it seems to), that’s a compiler bug.  Modules are not literally headers.

Comment: @Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeej: "*I'd appreciate if you put an answer down so I could mark it as the solution.*" That does appear to solve the problem, but it *shouldn't*. This seems like a compiler bug, because using `= {}` instead of `= default;` for the constructor *also* makes the compiler shut up. As does `= default;`ing it in the class definition rather than outside of it. And none of that ought to matter.

Comment: I also think I was not understanding the difference between the "module interface unit" and "module implementation unit".  I tried packing the whole thing into the module file, whereas I think I really should have broken up the declaration from the implementation by having just the declaration in the module, then implementation in a regular .cpp file.

Comment: Although come to think of it, I was initially attempting to learn how to use modules in an effort to avoid having to maintain two files for each of my class definitions, but the way this is going it seems I'm just replacing my header files for module interface definitions.

Comment: Please consider removing Windows/MSVC-specific stuff from your [mcve]. None of it should matter for the question.

Comment: well if this is indeed a compiler bug then context of this being in MSVC is pretty relevant.

Comment: @Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeej: "*the way this is going it seems I'm just replacing my header files for module interface definitions.*" Um... why? You're the one who choose to put this stuff in out-of-line definitions. I don't really see how that's the problem of the module system. You are perfectly capable of putting everything in the same file if you want. You're also perfectly capable of not putting everything in the same file. How you use the system is up to you.

Comment: Is it a compiler bug? If only we had a quick way to check against some kind of independent, dare I say, validation mechanism...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up separating implementation from interface:

winmain.cpp

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#include <memory>

import OSFrameworkWindows10Module;

int WINAPI wWinMain (
    _In_ HINSTANCE hinst,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE,
    _In_ PWSTR,
    _In_ int
)
{
    auto os_framework = std::make_unique<OSFramework>();
    return S_OK;
};
```

OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx

```
module;

#include <memory>

export module OSFrameworkWindows10Module;

export class OSFramework {
private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> _impl;
public:
    OSFramework();
    ~OSFramework();
};
```

OSFrameworkWindows10.cpp (new)

```
#include <memory>

import OSFrameworkWindows10Module;

using impl = struct OSFramework::impl {
    impl();
    ~impl();
};

impl::impl()
{}

impl::~impl() = default;

OSFramework::OSFramework() :_impl{ std::make_unique<impl>() } {}
OSFramework::~OSFramework() = default;
```

compiler output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Vegas22Metroidvania1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx
1>Compiling...
1>OSFrameworkWindows10Module.ixx
1>OSFrameworkWindows10.cpp
1>winmain.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Vegas22Metroidvania1.vcxproj -> D:\projects\Vegas22Metroidvania1\x64\Debug\Vegas22Metroidvania1.exe
```

I want to thank @alanbirtles for the tip about the `inline` keyword when used in a header file, because this got me thinking about how I would normally do this just using a header file and a source file.  This allowed me to re-read some blog posts about separating module interface and implementation and better understand what was being discussed.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a compiler bug. Here are a list of things that make the compiler cooperate, but none of them should matter:

- Declaring the destructor declaration `inline` (`inline ~OSFramework();`).
- *Defining* the out-of-line destructor `inline` (`inline OSFramework::~OSFramework() = default;`)
- Defining the out-of-line destructor with `= {}` instead of `= default;`.
- Moving the `= default;` constructor back to within the class definition.

None of these should fix anything. Member functions in modules are not implicitly `inline`, but that shouldn't cause a *multiple*-definition error. Importing a module is not like including a header.

And changing from `= default;` to `= {}` shouldn't change whether multiple definitions are created.

No, this is a compiler bug. I'd say that you should just `= default` it inline. It makes the code clearer anyway.